# Eclipse UML Designer: how to create template class

Tags: eclipse, uml-eclipse-plugin

I want to create a generic class for a class c++ model with the Eclipse plugin UML Designer. The plugin does not allow me to create a binding from the parameter class to the generic class with the binding association tool. When I attempt to do so the cursor gets a circle-backslash symbol when I hover over the target. The [documentation](http://www.umldesigner.org/ref-doc/implement-the-application.html#Class_Diagram) clears says I can do this, but I've tried everything without success.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to type the template parameter angle brackets and the template parameters using the "direct edit tool," i.e. by typing directly into the drawing. Typing them as part of the `Name` in the properties view does not create the generic class.